# Radio Buttons/Textbox Calculation: Deselect/Recalculate if User Changes Mind (Javascript/jquery/php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, radio-button, calculated-field

I have a php webform that I need help with.

This portion of the form uses javascript. Checking radio buttons next to options populates the fees into the corresponding textboxes and these textbox values calculate in the Grand Total textbox.

A user can only select one language for $75. They have an option to also select the corresponding credit for that language for $275.

If a person selects only a credit option, I want the corresponding language button to also select, and both fees should appear in the appropriate boxes and calculate correctly in the Grand Total.

If a person changes their mind, and selects a different language, the other radio button(s) from their former selection(s) should deselect and the corresponding fee textboxes should clear. This is where I am having trouble. When I change selections, the form doesn't always clear the subtotal textboxes from the previous selection, and it continues to add the fee from the previous selection in the Grand Total. (The Grand total of the form should never exceed $307.)

I am not an expert coder, and I acknowledge that the code I am using is not the most current/efficient. Since the original javascript in this form was written, jquery and php have become dominant. This form uses a mixture of old school javascript, jquery, and php. I welcome all possible solutions to accomplishing this task.

Hence, I appeal to this community, with gratitude for any time spent helping me learn.

http://jsfiddle.net/k5wL5vx6/

```
function total()
    {

var total=0;
var reg=0;  

if (window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745.checked) {
        reg=reg+75; window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value=75;
    } else {window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = ""; }

if (window.document.registration.dutch_WLC110_27750.checked) {
    window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745.checked = true; 
        reg=reg+232; window.document.registration.dutch_WLC110_27750_subtotal.value=232;
        reg=reg+75; window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value=75;
    } else {window.document.registration.dutch_WLC110_27750_subtotal.value = "";}

if (window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745.checked) {
        reg=reg+75; window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value=75;
    } else {window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = ""; }

if (window.document.registration.esl_WLC110_27751.checked) {
    window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745.checked = true;
        reg=reg+232; window.document.registration.esl_WLC110_27751_subtotal.value=232;
        reg=reg+75; window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value=75;
    } else {window.document.registration.esl_WLC110_27751_subtotal.value = ""; }

total = total + reg; 

   window.document.registration.amount1.value=total.toFixed(2);  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, just add 1,2,3,4 to the onClick() like this onClick(1). I also updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9rqofbsc/

```
function total(button) {
    if (button == 1) {
        $("#dutch_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", true);
        $("#dutch_WLC110_27750").prop("checked", false);
        $("#esl_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", false);
        $("#esl_WLC110_27751").prop("checked", false);
    }
    if(button == 2) {
        $("#dutch_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", true);
        $("#dutch_WLC110_27750").prop("checked", true);
        $("#esl_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", false);
        $("#esl_WLC110_27751").prop("checked", false);
    }
    if(button == 3) {
        $("#dutch_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", false);
        $("#dutch_WLC110_27750").prop("checked", false);
        $("#esl_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", true);
        $("#esl_WLC110_27751").prop("checked", false);
    }
    if(button == 4) {
        $("#dutch_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", false);
        $("#dutch_WLC110_27750").prop("checked", false);
        $("#esl_EENCx075_27745").prop("checked", true);
        $("#esl_WLC110_27751").prop("checked", true);
    }
    var total = 0;
    var reg = 0;

    if ($('#dutch_EENCx075_27745').is(':checked')) {

        reg = reg + 75;
        window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = 75;
    } else {
        window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = "";
    }

    if ($('#dutch_WLC110_27750').is(':checked')) {

        reg = reg + 232;
        window.document.registration.dutch_WLC110_27750_subtotal.value = 232;
        reg = reg + 75;
        window.document.registration.dutch_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = 75;
    } else {
        window.document.registration.dutch_WLC110_27750_subtotal.value = "";
    }

    if ($('#esl_EENCx075_27745').is(':checked')) {

        reg = reg + 75;
        window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = 75;
    } else {
        window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = "";
    }

    if ($('#esl_WLC110_27751').is(':checked')) {

        reg = reg + 232;
        window.document.registration.esl_WLC110_27751_subtotal.value = 232;
        reg = reg + 75;
        window.document.registration.esl_EENCx075_27745_subtotal.value = 75;
    } else {
        window.document.registration.esl_WLC110_27751_subtotal.value = "";
    }


    total = total + reg;

    window.document.registration.amount1.value = total.toFixed(2); //display the grand total.

}
```

Comment: This does work, and thank you, Michael. I saved a few lines by unchecking the entire group of buttons named 'credit' when a button of the other group (language) is checked. `$('input:radio[name=credit]:checked').prop('checked', false);` The jsfiddle is only a snippet of a much larger form with more options, so the script is quite long, but it is working and I am very grateful.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, I would appreciate if you would push the check mark next to my answer to accept it as the answer